# Converting Points shapefile to 3D polylines in QGIS (without Grass)

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, polyline-creation

I'm using QGIS 3.10 and am trying to come up with a way to create a shapefile of polylines with Z attribute attached, starting from a points shapefiles.

Both Saga/Convert Points to Lines and QGIS/Points to Path don't keep the Z values on the resulting polylines' vertices.

I've look up for hours online and I've only seen GRASS v.drape as a solution but GRASS hasn't been set up on my computer because of IT internal policies.

Has anyone any ideas about this?